# Get the requesting user in controller method of ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, angular, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am currently working on an ASP.NET Web app with angular as a front end. As a base, the new template present in VisualStudio 2019 for ASP.NET angular, with **Individual Authentication**.

This runs on dotnet core 3.0 Preview 4.

[image]

First a user is created through the *register* interface of the template application. Then when a request is made to a controller of the backend, I would like to get the ApplicationUser that made the request.

Is that possible? Do I need to put any sort of token in the header of the http request in the frontend? Do I need to do anything special in the backend?

Currently, the http request in the controller looks like this.

```py
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { error } from 'protractor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-classes-component',
  templateUrl: './classes.component.html'
})
export class ClassesComponent {
  public classes: Class[];
  public http: HttpClient;
  public baseUrl: string;
  public courseCodeValue: string;

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, private router: Router) {
    this.http = http;
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    this.refreshCourses();
  }

  public refreshCourses() {
    this.http.get<Class[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Courses/GetCourses').subscribe(result => {
      this.classes = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

The Controller looks like this:

```py
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CoursesController : Controller
    {

        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public CoursesController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }


        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IEnumerable<CourseDto> GetCourses()
        {
            var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;

            // Here the user is null
            return user.Courses.Select(item => new CourseDto
            {
                CourseCode = item.CourseCode,
                CurrentGrade = item.CurrentGrade
            });

        }
    }
```

The issue is that when I try to get the user that is making the http request with the usermanager, I get null. So I was wondering if I was missing something. Like prehaps some sort of token in the header of the request? Am I doing something wrong on the controller side?

**EDIT: here is the *Startup.cs* code**

```py
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code of Startup.cs

Comment: @TonyNgo I added the Startup.cs code in the post

Answer (score 0):

You can use "User.Identity.Name" to get the UserId of the User making the request then pass it to FindByIdAsync().

var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.Name);

or a db hit against the UserId(User.Identity.Name);

which ever works best for you.

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: @ShawmWalker This does not seem to work for me. The 'User.Identity' object looks like this. {System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity}
    Actor: null
    AuthenticationType: "AuthenticationTypes.Federation"
    BootstrapContext: null
    Claims: Count = 13
    CustomSerializationData: null
    IsAuthenticated: true
    Label: null
    Name: null
    NameClaimType: "name"
    RoleClaimType: "role"

So User.Identity.Name is just null in the request